# Unable to get TailwindCSS working with React + Vite

Tags: reactjs, installation, tailwind-css, vite

I followed the installation process for TailwindCSS from the official docs, but am unable to get it to work.

This is how my relevant files look:

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Default file structure is unchanged from Vite's setup. My js files are inside subdirectories in the /src

I've tried changing the vite.config.js as per recommendations, but neither the modified or unchanged versions work

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), eslint()],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    },
  },
});
```

Lastly, I of course tried restarting the server haha

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What makes you believe Tailwind is not working? Have you `import`ed `index.css` anywhere?

Comment: @Wongjn index.css is directly in my /src folder, as per Vite file setup. No default Tailwind stylings got applied, nor adding any Tailwind classes to my markup has any effect

Comment: Have you `import`ed `index.css` anywhere?

Comment: After breaking my head, I have just realized that I previously indeed removed the index.css import from main.jsx. This is embarrassing... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Having removed it previously, index.css file import was missing

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may help you

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ],
};
```